# Keeping in-memory data in sync with a file for long running Python script

Tags: python, database, file, python-2.7, memory

I have a Python (2.7) script that acts as a server and it will therefore run for very long periods of time. This script has a bunch of values to keep track of which can change at any time based on client input.

What I'm ideally after is something that can keep a Python data structure (with values of types `dict`, `list`, `unicode`, `int` and `float` – JSON, basically) in memory, letting me update it however I want (except referencing any of the reference type instances more than once) while also keeping this data up-to-date in a human-readable file, so that even if the power plug was pulled, the server could just start up and continue with the same data.

I know I'm basically talking about a database, but the data I'm keeping will be very simple and probably less than 1 kB most of the time, so I'm looking for the simplest solution possible that can provide me with the described data integrity. Are there any good Python (2.7) libraries that let me do something like this?

Comment: Look up the configparser module

Comment: How about Memcached or Redis?

Comment: I want it to be self-contained (except using a file for storage) so daemons are not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you don't need a fully blown database, as **it seems that all you want is atomic file writes**.  You need to solve this problem in two parts, serialisation/deserialisation, and the atomic writing.

For the first section, `json`, or `pickle` are probably suitable formats for you.  JSON has the advantage of being human readable.  It doesn't seem as though this the primary problem you are facing though.

Once you have serialised your object to a string, **use the following procedure to write a file to disk atomically, assuming a single concurrent writer** (at least on POSIX, see below):

```
import os, platform
backup_filename = "output.back.json"
filename = "output.json"

serialised_str = json.dumps(...)
with open(backup_filename, 'wb') as f:
     f.write(serialised_str)
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
     os.unlink(filename)
os.rename(backup_filename, filename)
```

While `os.rename` is will overwrite an existing file and is atomic on POSIX, this is sadly not the case on Windows.  On Windows, there is the possibility that `os.unlink` will succeed but `os.rename` will fail, meaning that you have only `backup_filename` and no `filename`.  If you are targeting Windows, you will need to consider this possibility when you are checking for the existence of `filename`.

If there is a possibility of more than one concurrent writer, you will have to consider a synchronisation construct.

Comment: Sweet! You're right, that was what I was looking for. I got carried away and made my question much more generic than it needed to be.

Comment: This is not atomic. For one there is no file locking. If two clients connect at the same time you can get undefined results. Either client1's or client2's changes can be lost, or they can become interleaved. Write a second version of this script that has a random-but-brief pause before renaming, then run multiple instances of both versions at the same time and witness the lack of atomicity. OP asked for an object persistence layer and *this* is the answer that was accepted?

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon Agreed, this is not atomic under the possibility of multiple writers.  I don't belief that is what the OP wanted, but I agree that the question was perhaps imprecisely phrased.

Comment: Looking at OPs answers to the other responses, I can only conclude that this question is dumb. It's essentially, "How do I do something already solved by every database, even though it may quite likely be overkill for my purposes? And also, for no good reason, I don't want to use an existing database."

Comment: Jesse, I believe you misunderstood. Only one thread will be working on the file. Using a database engine for this is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Well, since you know we're basically talking about a database, albeit a very simple one, you probably won't be surprised that I suggest you have a look at the [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module.

Comment: You're right. :) I'm considering it, but I'd prefer if there was an even simpler solution that can guarantee data integrity. A huge bonus if it stores the data in a human-readable format (which of course makes the writing much less efficient, but I can live with that since the writes will be relatively small and not very frequent).

Comment: @Blixt, well, I don't know of any *simpler* solution that can *guarantee* data integrity, and people have been trying to do what you want with XML-aware database columns for quite some time and... that's no much simpler either. Maybe you should just keep a human-readable (XML, or otherwise) *log* of every operation performed on your data, and write code to replay that log should mayhem ensue to your program :)

Comment: @Blixt: why not save to alternate config files every minute or so? That way if the server dies during write you have the data from a minute ago.

Comment: @katrielalex: That's a good solution too. I thought about doing incremental file saves and keeping a few of them, but alternating would work well too. I guess my question should have been "how do I store data to disk without running the risk of it being corrupted due to unexpected external errors" :)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason for the human readable requirement?

I would suggest looking at sqlite for a simple database solution, or at pickle for a simple way to serialise objects and write them to disk. Neither is particularly human readable though.

Other options are JSON, or XML as you hinted at - use the built in json module to serialize the objects then write that to disk. When you start up, check for the presence of that file and load the data if required.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know about the JSON module and can definitely see myself using it, but can I be sure that I don't run the risk of losing all data if the server dies during a normal file write? It's basically an advanced config file so being able to change it in any text editor while the server is not running would be nice. Also, doing SQL statements to update configurations just feels waaaay overkill.

Comment: Just don't overwrite the old files - create a new file for each write, and delete the old ones once they're not needed. Then you just need a way to check integrity of the most current file, and fall back to the previous one if the check fails.

Comment: Also have a look at the various ORM libraries that wrap a db and handle the sql for you. For instance, check out this example http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#creating-table-class-and-mapper-all-at-once-declaratively

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned your data is small, I'd go with a simple solution and use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module, which lets you dump a python object into a line [very easily](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#example).

Then you just set up a [Thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) that saves your object to a file in defined time intervals.

Not a "libraried" solution, but - if I understand your requirements - simple enough for you not to really need one.

EDIT: you mentioned you wanted to cover the case that a problem occurs during the write itself, effectively making it an atomic transaction. In this case, the traditional way to go is using "Log-based recovery". It is essentially writing a record to a log file saying that "write transaction started" and then writing "write transaction comitted" when you're done. If a "started" has no corresponding "commit", then you rollback.

In this case, I agree that you might be better off with a simple database like SQLite. It might be a slight overkill, but on the other hand, implementing atomicity yourself might be reinventing the wheel a little (and I didn't find any obvious libraries that do it for you).

If you do decide to go the crafty way, this topic is covered on the Process Synchronization chapter of Silberschatz's Operating Systems book, under the section "atomic transactions".

A very simple (though maybe not "transactionally perfect") alternative would be just to record to a new file every time, so that if one corrupts you have a history. You can even add a checksum to each file to automatically determine if it's broken.

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably go with `json` over `pickle`, but I'm considering it. My only worry is that just using simple file operations will run the risk of the file getting corrupted if the server dies during write. (Very unlikely, but a case I would like to cover).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to implement a database which provides [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees, but you haven't provided a good reason why you can't use one off-the-shelf. SQLite is perfect for this sort of thing and gives you those guarantees.

However, there is [KirbyBase](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/KirbyBase/1.9). I've never used it and I don't think it makes ACID guarantees, but it does have some of the characteristics you're looking for.

Comment: I don't need it to do all the requirements of ACID, but one argument for not using SQLite is that this is in essence just a config file that I want to make sure is not lost due to corruption, so it feels overkill. And a config file that is human readable is desirable. :)

Comment: Config files are not usually highly-trafficked, and changes to them are documented and deliberate. If you have a config file that is changing all the time, I would ask questions about the design of your system. BTW, I modified my answer to mention KirbyBase. If you don't need full ACID compliance, that's your best answer I'll bet.

Comment: Well basically, they are server-side configurations for the client. The clients are stupid (they rely on the server) with no persistent state. The client may want to update the name of something, then that should be stored in this configuration. So I believe there is no fault with the design, except that it "should" be a database, but in that case I am looking for a key-value store, not an SQL implementation. But again, I only need to ensure the data doesn't get corrupted, nothing else that comes with the db implementations.